# How to play audio in docker container on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, docker, audio, raspberry-pi, containers

I would like to play audio on my raspberry pi, the audio player (console application) should in a docker container. I have seen multiple articles on the web, they commonly suggest to add the `--device /dev/snd` to the `docker run`. I just can't seem to get the audio through. Audio should be played on the device that's attached via HDMI cable. I tried [sox player, I took ubuntu 18.04 as base image](https://ubunlog.com/en/sox-reproduce-mp3-terminal/) and also [this sample solution](https://ubunlog.com/en/sox-reproduce-mp3-terminal/). I'm flexible with with what the media player application is as this is a hobby project (would be nice that I can "pipe" an mp3 file to the program via bash while it is being streamed from somewhere). On the host I recently installed "Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software". (Release date is October 30th 2021, Kernel version: 5.10, whatever came with it). Pi 2 model B 1.1 (2014).

**UPDATE:** Audio does play on 3.5mm jack

It seems that by using the `--device /dev/snd` option, audio **does** play on the 3.5mm jack. I don't know though how to make this work on the HDMI.

Comment: The link to your sample solution is wrong. I'm trying to solve the same thing, looks like the solution will involve connecting to the host pulse server from within the container.

Comment: @Yusufk turns out that for me audio DID play, however not on the HDMI but the 3.5mm jack. Did you try to listen through 3.5mm jack?

Comment: I did not, and should have. Will give it a try again.